# Magento 1.9.2.4 not exporting simple products

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, export

I've run into a weird issue where my Magento site (1.9.2.4) isn't exporting all my products.  It successfully exports all my configurables, but that's it - none of the simple products contained within/associated to them.  Even when I change the export variables in Dataflow - Profiles to narrow it down to only the simple products (which I have set to not display individually), it doesn't export any of them.

In my searching I eventually came across this and tried running it, but it also didn't work:

```
<?php require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$data=array();
$data['entity'] = 'catalog_product';
$data['file_format'] = 'csv';
$data['form_key'] =Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); 
$data['export_filter']=array();

$model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
$model->setData($data);

$model->export();
$model->getContentType();

?>
```

That spit out the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat::getType() in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 1086
```

Any ideas or insight?  I'd hate to have to consider pulling it out of MySQL, that would be a massive bummer.